# How to retrieve Hotmail Spam filtered messages via POP3?

Tags: pop3, spam-prevention, hotmail

I use Thunderbird to retrieve e-mail messages from my Hotmail, but some of them are auomatically marked as spam in Hotmail. So I have to use www.hotmail.com to move them to Hotmail Inbox and then I can retrieve these to my Thunderbird Inbox.

Is there an easier way to get all messages from Hotmail via POP3, including spam (disabling Hotmail "spam filter", a Thunderbird add-on, another software...)?

PS1: I hate Hotmail...
server: pop3.live.com
port: 995 (SSL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to disable it completely, about all you can do is add your contacts to the Safe list in hotmail using your browser.

What pop address and ports are you using for hotmail?

I use Live mail and it pops my junk mail folder so I can look at it without going to the hotmail page in my browser.

[image]

Comment: see PS1 above :)